# displaying results from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Working on a project to display a list of cars

```
$username="username";
$password="password";
$database="listofcars";
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query2="SELECT * FROM cars";
$result=$mysqli->query($query2);
$num=$mysqli->mysqli_num_rows($result);
$mysqli->close();
echo "
<div class="item">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="imgcontainer"><img alt="Cars for sale" src="$carimage" width="380" height="380" /></div>
        <div class="details">
            <a href="$internallink" target="_blank">
                <h3 class="title"> $carname   <br />
                <span> $cartype </span></h3>
                <p>
                    $cardesc
                </p>
                <div class="button"><span data-hover="Order Car">Order Car</span></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need it to loop the results

database name: listofcars
tablename: cars

Field names

carsid
 carname
 carimage
 cartype
 internallink
 cardesc

Comment: In `$mysqli->mysqli_num_rows($result);` the method is not the right method. See https://php.net/mysqli_num_rows.

Comment: Mixing two different API's.  That's terrible

Comment: Then, you have some problems with your double quoted string: `echo"<div class="item">` will throw a _"syntax error: unexpected item"_.

Comment: I answered a similar post like this yesterday.

Comment: btw; you closed your connection too soon.

Comment: `@mysql_select_db($database)` you're mixing apis. Your code contains too many errors. Read the manuals and stick to the syntax.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are too many errors. The OP needs to read the manuals and to stick to the syntax.

Comment: you also have so many parse errors to make anyone's head spin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to leave the connection open until you are done and loop through it after running the query.

Something like

```
$servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "listofcars";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    //Query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cars";  

    $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     //Whatever you want to do for each row...
     echo "
     <div class='item'>
                    <div class='container'>
                        <div class='imgcontainer'><img alt='Cars for sale' src='".$row[carimage]."' width='380' height='380' /></div>
                        <div class='details'>
                            <a href='".$row[internallink]."' target='_blank'>
                                <h3 class='title'> ".$row[carname]."   <br />
                                <span> ".$row[cartype]." </span></h3>
                                <p>
                                ".$row[cardesc]."
                                </p>
                                <div class='button'><span data-hover='Order Car'>Order Car</span></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>"; 


 }

$conn->close();
```

Comment: why did you go change their `$mysqli` to `$conn`? maybe they're relying on that variable for other stuff.

Comment: Habit from my variable names I suppose, and originally I wasn't going to type the whole thing out, just a gist of what was wrong with the connection closing and the loop.

Comment: Fair enough. Yeah, this one could be a rabbit hole and they seem quite new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if it works.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "listofcars";

    // Create connection
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cars";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

?>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<div class="item">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <img alt="Cars for sale" src="<?php echo $row['carimage']; ?>" width="380" height="380">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
            <a href="<?php echo $row['internallink']; ?>" target="_blank">
                <h3 class="title"><?php echo $row['carname']; ?><br><span><?php echo $row['cartype']; ?></span></h3>
                <p><?php echo $row['cardesc']; ?></p>
                <div class="button">
                    <span data-hover="Order Car">Order Car</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: YES that worked thank you so much I forgot I need to filter the results by Open

Comment: $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql, 'SELECT from cars WHERE carstatus = '1';");

Comment: @TomLines is that the error it's giving you or is that what you want to do? You are already getting the result from the table using this line `$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);` there's no need to do anything else.